# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined at eval

Tags: webpack, babeljs, react-hot-loader, babel-polyfill

I'm experiencing an error that I believe is from webpack's side. Here it is:

```
index.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at eval (index.js:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:2548)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:622)
    at fn (bundle.js:48)
    at eval (client:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:2541)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:622)
    at bundle.js:668
    at bundle.js:671
```

My webpack is:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import path from 'path';
import isDev from 'isdev';
import { Dir } from './src/utils';

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

let Config = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    path.join(Dir.src, 'client.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(Dir.public, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    modules: [Dir.src, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: Dir.src,
      },
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
  ],
};

if (TARGET === 'build:prod' && !isDev) {
  Config = merge(Config, {
    bail: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: { publicPath: '/build/' },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        comments: false,
        dropDebugger: true,
        dropConsole: true,
        compressor: {
          warnings: false,
        },
      }),
    ],
  });
}

if (TARGET === 'server:dev' && isDev) {
  Config = merge(Config, {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client'],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
  });
}

const WebpackConfig = Config;
export default WebpackConfig;
```

This error only started to show up once I added what Redux suggests for server-side rendering. So I'm using hydration of store with **window.__PRELOADED_STATE__** in ./src/utils/store.js and it's also in **index.ejs** which is the file rendered to the client.

This is how it looks in my store.js:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';

export function configureStore(preloadedState) {
    let state;
    const middleware = [thunk, logger];
    const enhancer = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware));

    if (typeof preloadedState === 'undefined') state = {};
    else state = preloadedState;

    return createStore(reducers, state, enhancer);
}

/**
 Dehydrate (on server)
*/
export function dehydrate(store) {
    return JSON.stringify(store.getState()).replace(/</g, '\\u003c');
}

/**
  Rehydrate (on client)
*/
export function rehydrate() {
    // Grab the state from a global variable injected into the server-generated HTML
    const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
    // // Allow the passed state to be garbage-collected
    delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;

    return configureStore(preloadedState);
}
```

This is also my .babelrc if anything:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"],
        },
    },
    "plugins": [
        "babel-root-import"
    ],
}
```

Hope anyone can help with this - I haven't found a solution in my research and trials. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message in a non-React project.  I was building a bundle and using karma to run it in Chrome.  The solution was to change my webpack config from

```
target: 'node'
```

to

```
target: 'web'
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/